# Parent Child over id query

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

Example data:

```
id    parent    child     total  isParent isParentCHildthing
1     J          NA       5       1        1
1     B          NA       -5      0        1
1     J          NA       -10     1        1
1     B          NA        10     0        1
2     X          NA       -1      1        1
2     Y          NA        1      0        1
3     Z          NA        6      0        1
3     W          NA        7      0        1
3     P          NA        -6     1       1
3     R          NA        -7     1       1
3     TT         YY        500    0      0
```

Desired output:

```
id    parent   child total 
1       J       B     5     
1       J       B     -10
2       X       Y      -1
3       P       Z       -6
3       R       W       -7
```

In psuedo/english, for each "pair" in a given id, I want the parent and parent's total value and the "child" that goes with that parent would be determined by `isparent = 0 and total = total*-1  where isParent = 1`

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Suggest you look at Recusive CTEs in books online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirement, all you need is a simple self-join to find the one child that can be paired with each parent.

```
SELECT p.id, p.parent, c.parent AS child, p.total
FROM MyTable p
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable c
 ON c.isParent=0
 AND c.id=p.id
 AND c.Total = p.Total*-1
WHERE p.isParent=1
```

Note that this query will "break" if there are ever 2 or more parents with the same ID and the same Total, but according to your requirement, I am assuming that cannot happen.

Comment: right, I'm not sure if that case will happen yet either. I'm implementing this a little differently as all of the data in this resultset does not need this logic so I need to break it out based on some criteria and then union it back together, but I think this should work.